# Not getting id of newly created row using SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which i am creating an insert statement in a string and then executing the statement.
When i am using SCOPE_IDENTITY() to retrieve the id of newly inserted record it is returning NULL.

Please check the code below -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sgi_sp_SaveCompComponent] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Id int output, 
    @ComponentName nvarchar(50), 
    @VehicleSystemId nvarchar(10), 
    @NamingConvension nvarchar(50), 
    @IsSubcomponent bit=0, 
    @SubComponentId int=null,
    @CompanyID  int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Declare @TableName nvarchar(100) ='C'+ cast(@CompanyID as nvarchar(10)) +'_Components',
    @AssociatedTable nvarchar(100)='C'+cast(@CompanyID as nvarchar(10))+'_'+ +REPLACE(@ComponentName,' ','');
    DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Set @cmd='insert into '+@TableName+ '( ComponentName, VehicleSystemId, NamingConvension, IsSubcomponent, SubComponentId, AssociatedTable) values(''';
    set @cmd = @cmd + @ComponentName+''','''+ @VehicleSystemId+''','''+@NamingConvension+ ''','''+cast(@IsSubcomponent as nvarchar(10));
    if (@SubComponentId is null)
        set @cmd = @cmd +''',NULL,'''+@AssociatedTable +''')';
    else    
        set @cmd = @cmd +''','''+cast(@SubComponentId as nvarchar(10))+''','''+@AssociatedTable +''');';

    print (@cmd)
    exec (@cmd)
    set @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    print (@Id)
END
```

Can anybody help me out resolve this issue

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: Does that table that you're inserting data into actually **HAVE** an `IDENTITY` column??

Comment: The clue is in the first part of the name - Scope. `exec` creates a *new* scope. But it's not at all clear to me why you're constructing a string to do the insert - it looks like it could be a plain `INSERT ... SELECT` with no `exec` at all.